# How to get the streaming from server to react native

Tags: python, react-native, server, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I have a server working on the Raspberry Pi to do the streaming and it works on the website.
It is the code of the server:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, request
from camera import VideoCamera
import time
import threading
import os

pi_camera = VideoCamera(flip=False) # flip pi camera if upside down.

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html') 

def gen(camera):
    #get camera frame
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(pi_camera),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

But the question is my suppose using the react-native to get the streaming from the server.

I try to do it like this, but it has not any result:

```
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.homeContainer}>
            <Image
                source={{
                    uri: 'http://192.168.1.89:5000/video_feed',
                }}
                style={styles.image}
            />
        </View>

    );

};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    homeContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    image: {
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        resizeMode: "cover",
    },
});

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: text `"it doesn't work:"` is the most useless information. Do you get error message from flask in console? Do you get error message in browser? Do you get error in JavaScript console in browser? We can't run it, we can't read in your mind - you have to put all data in question (not in comments)

Comment: maybe `react-native` doesn't work with this kind of stream.